# JBoss 4.x to Glassfish 2022 and Java 6 to Java 8 causes 1 non-XA Resource Exception

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish

The datasources were non-XA and I don't get this error in JBoss.  I made one of my databases and driver XA, but I have a driver that I can't make XA.  Is there a Glassfish setting that would stop this exception from occurring?

```
Exception creating object: 
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources.  
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:119)
    at com.crlcorp.docqc.app.jdbc.DocQCDataConn.<init>(DocQCDataConn.java:27)
    at com.crlcorp.docqc.app.jdbc.DataLoader.getUnreviewedItems(DataLoader.java:111)
    at com.crlcorp.docqc.app.ejb.DocQCBean.getUnreviewedItems(DocQCBean.java:27)
```

Comment: Both JBoss and GlassFish allow only 1 non-XA resource to participate in a transaction. It's possible that you misconfigured the the XA connection and it is treated as a non-XA connection. According to https://glassfish.org/docs/latest/administration-guide#transaction-scope, an XA connection's resource type has to be set to `javax.sql.XADataSource`. Can you chec if your XA datasource has this resource type? If not, then you have 2 non-XA datasources, which is an issue.